# ¿Cual es la ruta de la tarjeta removible (SD card) en Android? Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, linux, xamarin, programación-móvil

Necesito ayuda para encontrar la ruta(path) de la tarjeta removible (Sd card extraible) de un dispositivo android, aqui el codigo:

```
         var list = System.IO.File.ReadLines("/proc/self/mountinfo");
        foreach (var i in list)
        {                    
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
 //Output:
/runtime/write /storage rw,relatime master:10 - tmpfs tmpfs 
rw,seclabel,mode=755,gid=1000

 / /storage/emulated rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime master:26 - sdcardfs 
 /data/media rw,seclabel,low_uid=1023,low_gid=1023,gid=9997,
 multi_user,mask=0007,reserved=20MB

 / /storage/590B-3A12 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime master:32 - sdcardfs 
 /mnt/media_rw/590B-3A12 rw,seclabel,low_uid=1023
 ,low_gid=1023,gid=9997,mask=0022

  /user/0 /storage/self rw,relatime master:10 - tmpfs tmpfs 
  rw,seclabel,mode=755,gid=1000

    //No puedo encontrarla con este codigo
   var path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
       //output: "/storage/emulated/0" que es la interna
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, he encontrado la respuesta, en Android 6+ se ha cambiado la ruta de la tarjeta extraíble a algo como esto "/storage/hex-code"

```
 /storage/590B-3A12 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime master:32 - sdcardfs 
 /mnt/media_rw/590B-3A12 rw,seclabel,low_uid=1023
,low_gid=1023,gid=9997,mask=0022
```

Siendo "/storage/590B-3A12" la ruta de la tarjeta extraíble, en mi dispositivo android un Samsung J7 Prime, Android 6.0.1.